# How to filter object array on javascript

Tags: javascript, html

im new in js

I want to make a code with onekeyup to search an object in an array. I don't know how to do it with one/specific parameter, not all of the parameter.
for ex. If I type tokyo, then it will not show anything because its not "name" parameter

script.js and index.html

```js
function checkOnKeyUp(input){

    const filtered = datas.filter(element =>  {
       for (const value of Object.values(element)) {
         if (
           value.toString()
         .toLowerCase()
         .includes(input.value.toLowerCase())
         )
         return true;
         
       }
    })  
    console.log('Name: ', filtered);
    document.getElementById("result").innerText=JSON.stringify(filtered)
}

const datas = [{
    "nickname":"abi","name":"Abi sholeh","id":123,"birth":"1999-05-09","address":"new york"},{"nickname":"abc","name":"abc james","id":112,"birth":"1999-05-04","address":"tokyo"}];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Pengenalan Javascript</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id='search' name='search' onkeyup="checkOnKeyUp(this)">
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting to happen. If I type tokyo, I get the expected object in the console.

Comment: @abyssus qwerty does my answer work for you. i have seen that you commented and deleted the comment. please let me know.

Comment: @yochanansheinberger oh, sorry.. i commented it didnt work.. but it helped me enough, and now it works. ill write down on your answer soon

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to the follow:

```js
datas.map(data => Object.values(data))
  .flat()
  .filter(value => 
    value.toString()
      .toLowerCase()
       .includes(input.value.toLowerCase()
  )
  .forEach(data => {
    data = 'nama';
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
function checkOnKeyUp(input){
    let value = input.value.toLowerCase();
    let filtered = datas.filter(element =>  {
       return element.name.toLowerCase() === value;
    })  
    console.log('Name: ', filtered.name);
    document.getElementById("result").innerText=JSON.stringify(filtered)
}
```

Comment: thanks, i still use my code, but the return code turned into "return element.name === value;" like yours

Comment: Your goal was to get a match even if only a partial of the name is given by the user?